# using backtracking recursion c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I need help with writing a backtracking recursion code in c++ that reach the min steps from 1 number to other number. you can only use +1 or *2
for example getting 23 from 10 by shortest is: ((10+1)*2)+1 has 3 steps,
or getting 65 from 12: (((12+1+1+1+1)*2)*2)+1 has 7 steps

TNX.

Comment: If you look at the posts in the past two days, there is another similar post about the shortest number of steps, using iteration.  The important part was that it was simplified using a math function. Search StackOverflow for "c++ shortest steps"

Answer (score 0):

Here is some help, the fundamental recursion function:

```
void recursive(unsigned int count)
{
  // Need to determine the end of recursion.
  if (count == 0)
  {
     return;
  }

  // Call the function again, which is recursion.
  recursive(count - 1);
}
```

Build upon this model to figure out how to implement your requirements.

Hint:  With recursion, one step at a time.  On a piece of paper, write down each step performed, along with all the values, until the operation is finished.  Look at the last step to determine how to stop the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int goal=23;
int result=1e9; ## set the count to infinity to optimize it
void solve(int curNumber,int step){
 if(goal == curNumber)  // Check if we reached the goal number
   result=min(result,step); // take the min of the solution, and number of   steps we took to reach the goal
 curNumber+=1  // add 1 to current Number
 solve(curNumber,step+1);
 curNumber-=1;   // backtrack on the add 1 solution
 curNumber*=2;  // choose the other path *2
 solve(curNumber, step+1);
}
```